# How do I find many maximums in a list in Mathematica

Tags: list, select, max, wolfram-mathematica

I have some data that i'm trying to analyze and it has many cycles where it returns to a maximum value. I want to be able to select and pull out all of those maximum values and make a trend line to see if it has good durability.

my question is much like [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966418/how-can-i-find-the-maximum-values-in-each-range-of-a-list-in-mathematica) but my segments are not uniform

The data is stored in a Tab delimited format {Timestamp,data,data,data,data,data,cycle#,boolean}
I've gotten it to be able to pull out each cycle with this code but how do i get the maximum at the same time?

```
#Importing the List#
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]] 
rawl = Import["SU8-20-50psi-6-29.txt", "TSV"];
date = {rawl[[4]][[1]]}
pressure = {rawl[[4]][[2]]};
forwardflow = {rawl[[4]][[3]]};
backwashflow = {rawl[[4]][[4]]};
forwardpressure = {rawl[[4]][[5]]};
backwashpressure = {rawl[[4]][[6]]};
cycles = {rawl[[4]][[7]]};
backwash = {rawl[[4]][[8]]};

length = Length[rawl]

iter = 4;

While[iter < length,
 iter = iter + 1;
 AppendTo[date, rawl[[iter]][[1]]];
 AppendTo[pressure, rawl[[iter]][[2]]];
 AppendTo[forwardflow, rawl[[iter]][[3]]];
 AppendTo[backwashflow, rawl[[iter]][[4]]];
 AppendTo[forwardpressure, rawl[[iter]][[5]]];
 AppendTo[backwashpressure, rawl[[iter]][[6]]];
 AppendTo[cycles, rawl[[iter]][[7]]];
 AppendTo[backwash, rawl[[iter]][[8]]]]

Select[rawl, #[[]][[7]] == 1 &]
```

I'm looking for a maximum in the 3rd data point

here is a sample of the data file

```
2015-06-30 16:11:15.628563  0.5 0.7 0.0 11.1    41.2    0   False
2015-06-30 16:11:15.889830  0.9 0.3 0.0 7.7 42.6    0   False
2015-06-30 16:11:16.090567  1.5 0.6 0.0 5.3 43.2    0   True
2015-06-30 16:11:16.338970  1.4 1.0 0.0 7.2 43.2    0   True
2015-06-30 16:11:16.456993  1.4 1.4 0.0 9.6 43.2    0   True
2015-06-30 16:11:16.580034  1.4 1.0 0.0 11.6    43.7    0   True
2015-06-30 16:11:16.692873  1.5 1.0 0.0 13.7    43.7    0   True
2015-06-30 16:11:16.804827  1.5 0.6 0.0 15.0    43.6    1   False
2015-06-30 16:11:16.937007  1.6 0.4 0.0 15.7    43.7    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.047861  1.6 0.0 0.0 15.8    43.6    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.158619  1.6 0.0 0.0 15.8    43.7    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.293030  1.5 0.0 0.0 15.7    43.9    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.404268  1.5 0.0 0.0 15.7    44.0    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.514991  1.5 0.0 0.0 15.6    44.8    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.650058  1.5 0.0 0.0 15.7    44.7    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.761827  1.5 0.0 0.0 15.7    44.7    1   True
2015-06-30 16:11:17.872931  1.8 0.0 0.0 15.7    44.1    2   False
2015-06-30 16:11:18.112676  0.4 0.0 0.0 15.0    42.4    2   False
```

<<< EDIT >>>> Here is my updated code that i have been trying but can't quite get it to work

`groups = Split[rawl, #1[[7]] == #2[[7]] &];      (* this works great*)
group = Max[groups[[3]][[All, 3]]]                (*This works too*)
Map[Max, groups[[#]][[All, 3]]] &                 (*So why wont these work?*)
Transpose[MapAt[Max /@ # &, Transpose[groups], 3]]`

Comment: Could you possibly edit in say ten lines of your data file, perhaps manually substituting something for the tabs if the posting process mangles the tabs? If you could do that and have a couple of your maxima in the data then someone could verify their idea should work with your full data file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the sample data, that always helps.

I'm not certain I understand all your question, but perhaps this will let you explain what I am missing.

This

```
rawl = Import["psi.txt", "TSV"];
rawl = Drop[rawl, 3];(*drop unwanted header rows?*)
{date, pressure, forwardflow, backwashflow, forwardpressure, 
  backwashpressure, cycles, backwash} = Transpose[rawl]
```

extracts the columns and stores your data in your variables.

This

```
Select[rawl, #[[7]] == 1&]
```

extracts those rows with cycles==1.

This extracts a maximum forward flow

```
maxff = Max @@ forwardflow
```

and this

```
Select[rawl, #[[3]] == maxff&]
```

finds all rows with forwardflow equal to that maximum.

If you can clarify what you need the final step to do then I'll try to finish this.

<<< EDIT >>>

Your latest description of the process is MUCH more helpful.

So here is my thinking:

1: You want to group items having the same number in the 7th column. Look up Split in the help pages. Look in the examples to see how to group on one particular column when you have rows of multiple columns. That will give you each group inside an extra layer of {} and all the groups will be inside a outer layer of {}.

2: Now you want to "do the same thing to every item", where each item is your group of rows from step 1. In Mathematica this is often best done with the Map function. Look that up in the help pages. The thing you want to do is the Max function and you need to see how to use subscripting to get the third column for that. This should give you the list of maxima. And Map will put all those results into a list for you so you get step 3 for free.

4: Then you can plot that resulting list.

So see if this gives you enough of an idea to get you started. If you can't figure out some part of the language then let me know and I'll give another hint.

Comment: This is great! I hadn't thought about finding all the ones equal to the original but I would also like to find the specific maximum of each cycle because i'm expecting for it to not always come back to the original maximum flow. I was Thinking a While loop to go though each cycle to find the max in that cycle and appending it to a list but i'm still thinking in c++ and i got lost in the syntax

Comment: It is clear to you what "the specific maximum  of each cycle" is, but I haven't got a clue what that means. Think "I have to write down directions to hand someone who knows nothing about what I've been working on for weeks and who is going to go do this on their own and come back with exactly the right answer on the first try." Perhaps with that I can write the correct line of code you need. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @bill , I'm new to Stackoverflow. so basically the pseudo-code would be  
1) Find all rows in a a cycle (with the same number in the 7th column)  
2) In those rows what is the maximum flow ( 3rd column)  
3) Append the maximum flow from step 2 to a list  
4) use the list from step three to make a trendline

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have edited my question above with the Split and Map code, i got Split to work but the Map function wont work. I think i'm close but i need some more hints.

Comment: Since you have successfully used Split to turn rawl into a list of groups you now want to use Map[f,groups] where f is going to be given a single group and needs to pick the item out of that group. You could literally define a function f[ group_ ] := ... and that might be the easiest way to understand this the first time. Or you could use Map[ ..anonymous function that uses # and & stuff, groups] if you are comfortable with doing that. Either way the function gets one group and returns the result from that group. Hint: think sort on 7th column and then return last item. Or think of other ways.

Comment: thank you so much for all the help. I posted an answer of what i did. Now i'm working with files of over 100,000 lines so if you see anything that could make the script faster or have any suggestions, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bill this is what i came up with and it works like a charm and is a LOT faster than anything with While loops.

```
(*import the data*)
rawl = Import["SU8-MA7.txt", "TSV"];
rawl = Drop[rawl, 3];(*drop unwanted header rows*)
{date, pressure, forwardflow, backwashflow, forwardpressure, backwashpressure, cycles, backwash} = Transpose[rawl];

(*Split it into groups and get the maximum of each group*)
totalcycles = Max[cycles]
groups = Split[rawl, #1[[7]] == #2[[7]] &];
f[group_] := Max[groups[[group]][[All, 3]]]
maximum = Map[f, Range[1, totalcycles]];
```